# Forcing proxy when running chrome over command line?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, proxy

I'm trying to run headless e2e tests with chrome and selenium. But having issues getting chrome to adhere to a proxy server. When just trying to get chrome to use a proxy server as per the documentation, it gets completely ignored.

Is there anything obviously wrong with these configurations?

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --proxy-server='p-uk1.biscience.com:80'

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --proxy-server='http=p-uk1.biscience.com:80;https=p-uk1.biscience.com:80'
```

In each instance, by either checking a 'what is my ip' style website I get my usual IP. And when checking `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` the connection continues to show a DIRECT configuration.

Using a mac, but exact same issue when trying same configuration on my 14.04 ubuntu box :(

Comment: You may need to include the proxy protocol. For example: `--proxy-server='socks://p-uk1.biscience.com:80'` (if it's a socks proxy)